# denotional semantic for while - fixed points

Tags: semantics, denotational-semantics

In my book it is written: 
$$[[\text{while b do S}]] = \text{FIX F}$$, where $Fg = cond (\beta[[b]], g\circ [[S]], id). $
What is cond ?
$[[\text{if b then S1 else S2}]] = cond (\beta[[b]], [[S1]], [[S2]])$.

I don't understand why we should use $FIX$. What it is FIX ?
For me it is sufficient:
$S[[\text{while b do S}]] = cond(\beta[[b]], [[\text{while b do S}]]\circ [[S]], id)$$

**DEFINITIONS**

$$S_{ds}[[\text{while b do S}]] = FIX F$$
where $Fg= \text{cond}(\beta[[b]], g\circ S_{ds}[[S]], id)$

$$FIX: ((State\rightarrow State)\rightarrow (State \rightarrow State)) \rightarrow (State \rightarrow State)$$
In brackets functions are partial.

Comment: Which is "your" book?

Comment: That's not a definition of "FIX": a type signature is not a definition of a function.  I appreciate the edit, but you need to keep reading in your textbook to find the definition of FIX.  And it's a good suggestion to edit the question to name your book.

Answer (score 6):

Your proposed alternate definition is no good.  It tries to define $[[\text{while b do S}]]$ in terms of $[[\text{while b do S}]]$.  That's a circular definition: you can't define something in terms of itself.

"FIX" typically refers to the least fixpoint, and is a way of avoiding circularity.  See your textbook for background on fixpoints and the precise definition of the "FIX" operator.

Comment: I edited my first post. Could you try to explain it your own words ? I understand that we must avoid circular, but I don't understand  way for that.   Maybe some other example ?

Comment: @user40545, you should do more research.  It's your responsibility to read your book. If the book is any good, it will have a definition of the FIX operator.  If it doesn't, throw it away and get a better book.